# Bitwise or cause overflow when num > 2147483647

Tags: javascript, optimization

Refer to this article:
[math-round-vs-hack](http://jsperf.com/math-round-vs-hack/3)

We have Math functions optimized.

We use `(num+0.5)|0` instead of `Math.round()`.

But there's a problem which make confused that when num > 2147483647, it comes out wrong results.

```
function round(n) {
    return (n + 0.5) | 0;
};
```

`round(2147483648)` will return -2147483648

And according to wikipedia:

> 2147483647 in computing
>
> The number 2,147,483,647 is also the maximum value for a 32-bit signed integer in >computing. It is therefore the maximum value for variables declared as int in many >programming languages running on popular CPUs, and the maximum possible score (or amount >of money) for many video games. The appearance of the number often reflects an error, >overflow condition, or missing value.[8] Similarly, "(214) 748-3647" is the sequence of >digits represented as a United States phone number and is the most common phone number >listed on web pages.[9]
> The data type time_t, used on operating systems such as Unix, is a 32-bit signed integer >counting the number of seconds since the start of the Unix epoch (midnight UTC of 1 >January 1970).[10] The latest time that can be represented this way is 03:14:07 UTC on >Tuesday, 19 January 2038 (corresponding to 2,147,483,647 seconds since the start of the >epoch), so that systems using a 32-bit time_t type are susceptible to the Year 2038 >problem.[11]

How can I handle this situation to ensure good performance?

Comment: `if (n <= 2147483647) { return (n + 0.5) | 0; } else { return Math.round(n); }` :)

Comment: Interestingly enough I added this on to my fiddle, and it turns out that the comparrisson slows the function down, so that (even for small numbers) in most browsers this is slower than just doing math.round(), and on the iPhone it is almost as slow.

Comment: @deceze I'm not sure it's a good idea 'cause I have to compare n and 2147483647 every time. :)

Comment: Sure, but at least it works. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Use Math.round()

I would file this entire exercise under "why you should never do micro optimizations". Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/toxicsyntax/a5rWm/2/

Here is some results from different browsers:

- Firefox 11: round: 185ms bit_round: 123ms (for 100000000 iterations)
- Chrome 18: round: 99ms bit_round: 96ms (for 100000000 iterations)
- IE 9: round: 227ms bit_round: 123ms (for 1000000 iterations)
- IPhone 4, Safari: round 399ms, bit_round 32ms (for 1000000 iterations)

Sure, in the best case the bitwise round function is way faster than using Math.round(), but does it really matter? Worst case Math.round() still handles several millions rounds pr. seconds without problems.

How many do you roundings do you have to do? I don't expect you would ever have to round numbers in javascript, except for displaying numbers, and even if you are displaying thousands of rounded numbers pr. second, Math.round() is still going to be fast enough for you.

*Update*

And also, regarding micro optimazations in general, be sure to check out the article from Coding Horror: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html

Micro optimazation is very, very rarely a good idea.

Comment: Forgive me. This is a big application and it's performance is not good.So we try everything to make it faster..

Comment: And you should - but not by doing micro optimazations. I'm very sure that this is not what is making your application slow, and you are wasting your time by looking in to this "problem". What you should do is profile, find bottlenecks and concentrate on them. In client side javascript, slowness is 95% of the time related to the DOM. Start out by googling something like "DOM access optimazation" and work from the articles you get there.

Comment: Perhaps you're right in most case, I'll surely concentrate on bottlenecks. As in your test result, the performance improvement is not small on mobile device like Iphone, our application draw charts and run on ipad, which should use `Math.round()` often, so I think it's kindly worth it to do some micro optimizations.

Comment: Try to use the profiler in firebug to count how many times the round function is called. If this number is below, say, 1000 for then I would wager you could improve the speed of the round function all you want - the user would never notice it. If the number is really high, then yes, this would appear to a bottleneck you could optimize.

Comment: @ThemeZ So in the best case you can save ~350ms per 1 million iterations. How often is that function called per second? A thousand times? For your usual chart, probably a few hundred times when drawn (not per second), so in the best of all cases you saved about 0.35ms of a second. Optimizing software by **guessing** where most of the time is spent just doesn't work.